# group lines according to first word

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, grep

How can I modify the following content of a file:

```
cat:persian/young-1
cat:winter/young-2
cat:summer/wild-3
dog:persian/young-1
dog:winter/young-2
dog:summer/wild-3
```

To :

```
cat:persian/young-1
cat:winter/young-2
cat:summer/wild-3

dog:persian/young-1
dog:winter/young-2
dog:summer/wild-3
```

It's not specific to dog or cat, it's more of symbolic representation of whatever the first word/term is

Comment: Will the first word always be delimited by a colon?

Comment: Yes it'll always be in cat: or dog: format but a solution to something without being delimited by a colon is also welcomed @Jesse_b

Comment: Please clarify whether the blank line in the output is required or cosmetic.

Comment: @agc: The blank line is really the only change between input and desired output.

Comment: @Jesse_b, D'oh!  Total misreading on my part...  Thanks.

Comment: `uniq` can do it, but you have to hardcode the width of the first field, which makes it frustratingly useless: `uniq --group -w 4 file`

Comment: @glennjackman yes. but that actually solved my specific problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
awk -F: 'NR>1 && $1 "" != last {print ""}; {print; last = $1}'
```

The `""` is to force string comparison. Without it, it wouldn't work properly in input like:

```
100:foo
100:bar
1e2:baz
1e2:biz
```

Where `100` and `1e2` would be compared as numbers.

Answer (score 7):

Here's one way.  If the first field isn't the same as the one in the previous line, print a break....

```
$ awk -F: '$1!=a&&a{print ""}{a=$1}1' myfile
cat:persian/young-1
cat:winter/young-2
cat:summer/wild-3

dog:persian/young-1
dog:winter/young-2
dog:summer/wild-3
$
```

Explanation:

- `-F:` = set the field delimiter to `:`
- `$1!=a&&a` = if first field is not equal to variable "a" (the previous first field), and variable "a" is set to something (i.e. we're not dealing with the very first line in the file)
- `{print ""}` = print a blank line
- `{a=$1}` = for every line read, set variable "a" to the first field
- `1` = print the line

Comment: _and variable "a" is set to something_ is actually _"a" is set no a non-empty string that is none of the representations of the zero number (like "0", "0e2", " 0 ", 1e-500... possibly 0x0, 0x0p4... with  some implementations)_

Answer (score 1):

I tried with this way

```
en ~]# awk '/cat/{print $0}' filename| sed '$s/.*/&\n/g';awk '/dog/{print $0}' filename

cat:persian/young-1
cat:winter/young-2
cat:summer/wild-3

dog:persian/young-1
dog:winter/young-2
dog:summer/wild-3
[root@praveen ~]#
```

Comment: needs a tweak to avoid that first blank line of output, in order to match the desired reult ?

Comment: @steve: That's easy, just pipe it through `tail -n +2`.  Nobody said you have to do everything in `awk`.

Answer (score 1):

You could employ the `sed` editor for this job too:

```
$ sed -e '
   $q;N
   P
   /^\([^:]*\):.*\n\1:/!{x;p;x;}
   D
' input

cat:persian/young-1
cat:winter/young-2
cat:summer/wild-3

dog:persian/young-1
dog:winter/young-2
dog:summer/wild-3
```

Basic idea is to have 2 lines at any time in the pattern space. Compare the strings before the leading colons ":" in the pattern space. Should they not match, means a
changeover of an animal is detected, and we promptly display an empty line.

Answer (score 0):

It could be done with awk:

```
awk -F: ' $0!="" && last!="" && $1!=last"" {print""} {last=$1} 1'
```

- `-F :` used to split the fields on a `:` character.
- `$0 != ""` is required to avoid converting one  empty line into three.
  This allows re-processing an already processed file without adding empty lines.
- `last != ""` is required to avoid the file first line (where last is empty).
- `$1 != last""` compare the present first field to the previous one.
  The trailing `""` ensure that the comparison is done in text mode. Otherwise, equivalent (to `awk`) numeric values will be seen as equal, like:

  ```
  7:first line
  7e0:second line
  7.0000:third line
  7.000000000000000000008:fourth line
  ```
- `{print""}` print an empty line (if all the tests above match).
- `{last=$1}` store the line first field in the variable `last`.
- `1` print the line contents (always).